# Google Maps Darkened Areas

Tags: google-maps, google-earth

Does anybody know why or how areas on Google Earth become "darkened"? This is not in reference to deliberate places on the maps that are obfuscated by a government agency's request.

For instance, in google maps, type in: 1398 road H, Garberville, CA. Then switch to Earth view and zoom out a ways. A specific affected darkened area emerges. I am wondering if anybody knows what technically causes this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Wutnaut just open http://maps.google.com and paste 1398 road H, Garberville, CA. into the address and zoom out a bit. It shows a darkened triangle.

Comment: I think these images were taken at night and the others at daytime and Google paste these together to get the whole image. Normally they would use daytime images but perhaps of that specific area at that specific altitude they didn't have daytime images available.

Comment: The day vs night concept was my initial guess, however, it would seem like this anomaly should be more frequent then?

Comment: Well, I think they have lots of images of multiple passes but if there was something wrong with the daytime image of just that particularly area they needed to fallback on a nighttime image. I don't think it happens that often so they have daytime images of almost 99% of everything. (That's my guess)

Comment: There aren't enough details to reproduce the problem nowadays. Nowadays, there is no Earth layer. Is it supposed to happen in the Satellite layer? Is it still happening in May 2023?